# Removal of sink node in pagerank

Tags: information-retrieval, pagerank

Why don't we remove sink nodes altogether while considering importance of the pages using pagerank algorithm? Why do we care about sink nodes and take Z matrix in consideration so as to compensate for all zero columns(sinks) in probability transition matrix M? If there is some important reason in retaining them can anyone please tell what is it?

Comment: A sink node will reference itself, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might contain genuine or fake information, we cannot decide that using an algorithm